# Monkey-banana problem in Prolog

Tags: ai, prolog

> **The monkey-banana problem**: There many variations to this problem, but the basic premise is that a monkey is in a room with a banana and
>   a chair, and the monkey cannot reach the banana until he moves the
>   chair close to the banana (so as to reach it), then climbs the chair
>   and gets the banana.
>
> (**Note** : Often times, the chair is replaced with a box or a similar
>   object that the monkey can climb on. Also, a stick may be added to the
>   mix, which the monkey needs to swing at the banana in order to make it
>   drop to the floor.)

I came up with this program to solve a simple monkey-banana problem in AI (no stick).  I think it's overly simple, but I would like to know what you think.

```
on(floor,monkey).
on(floor,chair).
in(room,monkey).
in(room,chair).
in(room,banana).
at(ceiling,banana).

strong(monkey).
grasp(monkey).
climb(monkey,chair).

push(monkey,chair):-
    strong(monkey).

under(banana,chair):-
    push(monkey,chair).


canreach(banana,monkey):-
    at(floor,banana);
    at(ceiling,banana),
    under(banana,chair),
    climb(monkey,chair).

canget(banana,monkey):-
    canreach(banana,monkey),grasp(monkey).
```

Should I add location attributes as well? I think that I have hard-coded a lot of things, or maybe having the stick included in the problem would make a better search tree?